# Can't access SQL Server via IIS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis

I want to run my ASP.NET MVC application on the local IIS 8 server but I can't  get access to SQL Server 2014. Both IIS and SQL Server run on the same host and I am using Windows 8. This is what I have done so far:

In the application I created a model called `Employee`:

```csharp
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to connect to the database with using Entity Framework so I created another class called `EmployeeDbContext`:

```csharp
public class EmployeeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

I have only one `Home` controller:

```csharp
public string Index()
{
    EmployeeDbContext employeeDbContext = new EmployeeDbContext();
    return "Hello world";
}
```

I am using SQL Server 2014 Express engine with Windows Authentication and the name of my computer is ZSÓTÉ. Here is the connection string from the `web.config`:

```xml
<add name="EmployeeDbContext" 
     connectionString="Server=ZSÓTÉ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In the `Global.asax` I didn't set any initializer strategy so by default if the `Test` database doesn't exist, then the application should create it automatically.

After that I set on the properties window to use IIS Local Server and I create  a virtual directory for the application. So far everything is ok, I can see the application in the IIS manager and I set to run under the `DefaultAppPool`. After that I set all the permissions of the project folder for the IIS `APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` object. The settings are fine I can access the application from the IIS server perfectly.

Finally I created a login for `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` in SQL Server Management Studio and I set these two roles: `public` and `dbcreator`. But even after all these setups the application doesn't work correctly via IIS.

Though I get the "Hello world" message on the browser, but the `Test` database is never created. The strangest thing is if I make some malicious change in the connection string, I don't even get any compilation error, just the "Hello world" message in the browser.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: "I created a login for IIS "APPOOL\DefaultAppPool". According to your connection string you are using _Integrated Security_. You need to see what _windows user_ your app pool is running under. That's not _APPOOL\DefaultAppPool_, its more likely _LOCAL\System_ or something like that. _Thats_ the windows user you need to add. Of more concern is that the connection failure is not being logged anywhere by your application.

Comment: Alternaitvely (and simpler) you could use SQL authentication which means you just use a hard coded user / pwd in your connection string.

Comment: It is supposed to run under the "DeafaultAppPool" virtual account. But just to be sure, I change the pool identity to my account (set the userID, ant the password) on the IIS, so when I run the application, the task manager shows me the w3wp process is running under my account. But it still doesn't work. Did I miss some mandatory installation maybe? Cause it is just strange if i remove the provider name attribute e.g. from the connectionstring, I should recieve a compilation error, but I don't get anything.

Comment: Until we get an error its difficult to troubleshoot in this manner. If you make the connection string invalid you'll get a runtime error not a compile error. But you're not even getting a runtime error. Sometimes with EF it does lazy loading and it won't even connect until you request data _and_ display it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The database is created the first time you access to entities.
Try to do this:

```
public string Index()
{
    EmployeeDbContext employeeDbContext = new EmployeeDbContext();
    employeeDbContext.Employees.ToList();
    return "Hello world";
}
```

At this point you will receive an error if db creation does not work.

Next steps if something still does not work:
In the connection string use .\SQLEXPRESS because could happen everything to accents.
Assign to the user in SQL Server system administration role. If it work you then start to reduce rights (or, better, change approach).

Comment: Accessing to the entities solved the problem, thank you very much!